# How to get particular time format inside the text file

Tags: ex-mode

I want to paste particular date format (`mm--dd-yyyy`) using following terminal command in ex command mode:

```
:r !echo $(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
```

Its print the current file name instead of printing date,

After that I try another command:

```
:r date+"%d-%m-%Y"
```

Its also failed , It returns following error:

```
**/bin/bash: /tmp/vptQGvY/8: No such file or directory
shell returned 1
E485: Can't read file /tmp/vptQGvY/8
Press ENTER or type command to continue**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
:r !date +"\%d-\%m-\%Y"
```

But preferred way to do this would be to use `strftime()`. Here's a [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time) for more info